# Android Switch. On or Off without user selection

Tags: android

Is there away to change the state of the switch, either on or off without the user pressing it?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html

Comment: Are you trying to set the state of the switch via code? EG: For default settings and such?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the inherited methods from class `android.preference.TwoStatePreference`, there you'll find `setChecked` method:

```
public void setChecked (boolean checked)
```

It sets the checked state and saves it to the `SharedPreferences`. So `SwitchPreference.setChecked(true)` and `SwitchPreference.setChecked(false)` should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programatically...

```
setChecked(true);
setChecked(false);
```

This is inherited from the superclass TwoStatePreference.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#setChecked(boolean)